# Authenticated HTTP POST with XML payload using Python urllib2

Tags: python, http, post, ironpython, urllib2

I'm trying to send a POST message with a purely XML payload (I think) using urllib2 in IronPython.  However, everytime I send it, it returns Error code 400 (Bad Request).

I'm actually trying to mimick a Boxee remove queue item call for which the actual data packets looks like this (from WireShark):

```
POST /action/add HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.16.3 (Windows  build 7600; en-US; beta) boxee/0.9.21.11487
Host: app.boxee.tv
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Cookie: boxee_ping_version=9; X-Mapping-oompknoc=76D730BC9E858725098BF13AEFE32EB5; boxee_app=e01e36e85d368d4112fe4d1b6587b1fd
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 53

<message type="dequeue" referral="3102296"></message>
```

I'm using the following python code to send the POST:

```
def PostProtectedPage(theurl, username, password, postdata):

    req = urllib2.Request(theurl, data=postdata)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    try:
        handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except IOError, e:                  # here we are assuming we fail
        pass
    else:                               # If we don't fail then the page isn't protected
        print "This page isn't protected by authentication."
        sys.exit(1)

    if not hasattr(e, 'code') or e.code != 401:                 # we got an error - but not a 401 error
        print "This page isn't protected by authentication."
        print 'But we failed for another reason.'
        sys.exit(1)

    authline = e.headers.get('www-authenticate', '')                # this gets the www-authenticat line from the headers - which has the authentication scheme and realm in it
    if not authline:
        print 'A 401 error without an authentication response header - very weird.'
        sys.exit(1)

    authobj = re.compile(r'''(?:\s*www-authenticate\s*:)?\s*(\w*)\s+realm=['"](\w+)['"]''', re.IGNORECASE)          # this regular expression is used to extract scheme and realm
    matchobj = authobj.match(authline)
    if not matchobj:                                        # if the authline isn't matched by the regular expression then something is wrong
        print 'The authentication line is badly formed.'
        sys.exit(1)
    scheme = matchobj.group(1) 
    realm = matchobj.group(2)
    if scheme.lower() != 'basic':
        print 'This example only works with BASIC authentication.'
        sys.exit(1)

    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
    authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
    req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
    try:
        handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    except IOError, e:                  # here we shouldn't fail if the username/password is right
        print "It looks like the username or password is wrong."
        print e
        sys.exit(1)
    thepage = handle.read()
    return thepage
```

However, whenever I run this, it returns Error 400 (Bad Request)
I know the authentication is correct because I use it elsewhere to fetch the queue (and I can't imagine it's not used, otherwise how would it now which account to apply the change to?)

Looking at the network capture, could I simply be missing adding some headers to the request?  Probably something simple, but I just don't know enough about python or HTTP requests to know what's what.

**Edit**: BTW, I'm calling the code as follows (it's actually dynamic, but this is the basic idea):

```
PostProtectedPage("http://app.boxee.tv/action/add", "user", "pass", "<message type=\"dequeue\" referral=\"3102296\"></message>")
```

Comment: One tip.  Try getting it working using curl on the command line first. You can capture that using curl's debug options and that might give you some clues.  It's also possible that in python you need to forge the curl User-Agent header because some programmatic HTTP interfaces reject unknown user agents, unfortunately.

Another possibility is you need to mimic the way boxee provides Cookies back to the server.

Comment: Hmmm, good points.  I ignored the user agent and cookies since the get process worked fine without it.  Will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: I tried setting up an account and testing this myself, but I can't figure out where on boxee.tv to trigger this request normally so I can see it in Wireshark.

Comment: Did you get your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
curl -v -A 'curl/7.16.3 (Windows  build 7600; en-US; beta) boxee/0.9.21.11487' \
 -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -u "USER:PASS" \
 --data '<message type="dequeue" referral="12573293"></message>' \
 'http://app.boxee.tv/action/add'
```

But I get `400 Bad Request` if I try to remove a referral ID that isn't currently in the queue. If you're using the same referral ID as you detected from Wireshark, that's very likely what's happening for you, too. Use

```
wget -nv -m -nd --user=USER --password=PASS http://app.boxee.tv/api/get_queue
```

to make sure what you're trying to remove is actually in the queue.